# LIKE function SQL

Tags: php, sql

I've been using the function `LIKE` in this statement however its not doing what I expected for it to do, Basically a user on my site has a `subject` which usually looks like this `hello welcome to my #room hows it going #fun` and what im using is the `LIKE` function to select all users with the `subject` containing `#fun` my statement looks like this;

```
$search = 'fun';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usr_users` WHERE `subject` LIKE '%$search%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

however when the query runs it only selects the users which have fun at the begining of their `subject` or not at all. is there a different function I can use to select words from within in the `subject` not just the first word.

Comment: Btw Lewis; you're working with a deprecated MySQL API and it will be removed from future PHP releases. If and when you do upgrade to a new version of PHP, you will have to rewrite your code. Look into these to be ahead of the game http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php or http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need a `%` at the beginning of the string to search.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usr_users` WHERE `subject` LIKE '%$search%'";
```

--- UPDATE ---

It may be failing you because you may need to escape the data. check for errors mysql_error() against your query. It might be throwing you something about it. mysql_real_escape_string(). That # could be the culprit if it's part of your actual query. Or use htmlspecialchars() or something like that to echo out the query.

Comment: Okay this doesn't resolve the issue though still not giving me the results I need; thankyou however for the information.

Comment: Are you sure there is relevant matches in the table?

Comment: Not my dv btw David. @LewisTyler it may be failing you because you may need to escape the data. check for errors `mysql_error()` against your query. It might be throwing you something about it. `mysql_real_escape_string()`. That `#` could be the culprit if it's part of your actual query. Or use `htmlspecialchars()` or something like that to echo out the query.

Comment: @DarylGill Yes there are relevant matches in my database the example above for the subject is one that is input'd into the database

Comment: @Fred-ii- there was an error; thankyou for the advice. works now thankyou.

Comment: @LewisTyler You're welcome Lewis. I feel that David should edit his answer in order to reflect that.